# iPhone HTTPS works as webpage, fails as web-app

Tags: iphone, web-applications, https, iphone-web-app

I configured my web server to use HTTPS instead of HTTP. I used openssl to generate an X509 certificate and private key. When I connect using FireFox it warns me of an "Untrusted Connection" and allows me to add an exception to continue. When I connect using my iPhone's Safari web browser it does the same thing. I hit accept to the security prompt and it works fine.

I add the web page to my home screen so that I can run it as a web-app. When I open the web-app I see the following prompt:

> **Cannot Open MyWebApp** MyWebApp could not be opened. The error was: "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be mydomainnamehere.com" which could put your confidential information at risk.:". **CLOSE or RETRY**

If I hit close the web-app closes. If I hit retry I see the prompt again. There is no option to trust the site and continue.  How can I get this to work? I'd like to use HTTPS to encrypt the sensitive data. It is a private site I use to access files remotely. It is not intended for public use.

Comment: Sound like something to report here https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

There are two solution. 1) use a trusted certificate and 2) is to add the untrusted certificate to your iPad. This way your iPad will consider it as trusted.

Download the certificate (with Chrome for example), put the cert as an attachment on an email. Open this email on your iPad and click the attachment/cert and install it. Thats it!